# How to pass variables in TS files in NGX Translate inside a function

Tags: angular, internationalization, i18next, ngx-translate

I wanted to create a function so that we can pass the params  of translation.
Here is the service file.

```
translateGlobalTextWithParameters() {
    this.globalTextDataWithVariables = this.translateService.instant(
      'dashboard.HELLO',
      {
        value: 'world',
      }
    );
    return this.globalTextDataWithVariables;   \\\ return any type
  }
```

Here is how I call the service in the component.ts. this.helloworld returns string

```
helloWorld= '';
translateText(){
this.helloWorld =
      this.globalTextTranslationServiceService.translateGlobalTextWithParameters();
}
```

Here is my translation file

```
"dashboard": {
  "HELLO": "hello {{value}}"
}
```

In the end, I'm getting missing language key errors. What am I doing wrong, how can I solve this error?

Comment: how did you init ngx-translate ? you should have some code in your app.component.ts or app.module.ts defining the default language etc... See §1-4 from [AOT official documentation](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#aot)

Comment: The default language is en

Comment: can you show your code (by editing the question) defining all that stuff ?